# Flex BlazeDS consumer not subscribed

Tags: apache-flex, blazeds, consumer

My flex frontend is using BlazeDS/Tomcat to collect realtime data.
I am using a plain consumer over a standard streaming-amf channel.

```
<mx:ChannelSet id="channelSet">
 <mx:StreamingAMFChannel id="streamingAMF" url="messagebroker/streamingamf/" />
</mx:ChannelSet>
<mx:Consumer id="consumer" channelSet="{channelSet}" 
             channelConnect="consumer_channelConnectHandler(event)" 
             channelDisconnect="consumer_channelDisconnectHandler(event)" 
             message="consumer_messageHandler(event.message)"  
             fault="consumer_faultHandler(event)"
             resubscribeAttempts="-1" 
             resubscribeInterval="2000"/>
```

This setup **works just fine in all setups** but the following. Visible discrepancies are:

- Windows 2008 server vs Linux or older Windows
- Java 1.7.0 vs 1.6.0
- Tomcat 7.0 vs 6.0

The symptom is *consumer.subscribed* is never set to *true*, although *consumer.subscribe()* is invoked, and seen on the server side:

```
[BlazeDS]13:49:03.922 [DEBUG] [Endpoint.FlexSession] FlexSession created with id '275E7BE0E76EC4C4E8DB08F770BE2846' for an Http-based client connection.
[BlazeDS]13:49:03.922 [INFO] [Endpoint.General] Channel endpoint skydata-streaming-amf received request.
```

I checked all logs (catalina, stdout and stderr) without any visible clue on what went wrong. Once again, this exact same setup works in all other instances

Any ideas?

Comment: If it is related to the platform, you should verify path separators (Windows uses \, Linux uses /) and encoding.  Also, switching the BlazeDS log to "Debug" might produce better error output.

Comment: This is working fine on a Windows 2003 server. I don't think it's a path problem. BlazeDS is already set to Debug and not showing significant errors.

Comment: Here is a related question from myself http://tinyurl.com/7vhnhzg. I could not get BlazeDS to work on Tomcat 7 with streaming. Did you guys compile BlazeDS from SVN or did you use default spring-flex intergated libraries?

Comment: We use default libs, but didn't try version 4 for Tomcat 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from **Tomcat 7.0** reverting back to Tomcat 6.0 fixed it right away.
There is a hack available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13024000/tomcat-doesnt-do-blazeds-streaming-after-version-7-0-27) to fix BlazeDS w/ Tomcat 7.

Answer (score 0):

Once check the connected property of the consumer. And also post the channel set configuration, if possible.

I have been using Tomcat7 and found no problem as such, rather I am using it as it is based on Servlet 3.0 specification and may support multiple clients. I found it [here](http://blog.hiraash.org/2012/04/13/scaling-blazeds-with-servlet-3-concurrency/).

Comment: ChannelSet configuration added. Since consumer_channelConnectHandler is never invoked my guess is consumer.connnected won't change. Somehow BlazeDS is not able to send the connection ack back to the browser.